# How to "clear out" the receive buffer on a Java DatagramSocket?

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I have a Java program that is constantly being sent UDP data from an external system.

Periodically, we need to stop receiving data (because another machine is handling it). During those times, my socket reader thread goes into a sleep loop. When it is time to start receiving packets, I go into `socket.receive(Packet)` again and have a buffer full of packets that I should *not* be handling. (The data came while in the "stop time".)

Is there a way to clear the buffer of a DatagramSocket?

If not, what is the best alternative? Set the buffer size to 0 when I go into the wait state and bring it back when I start to service packets again? Close the socket when I while I wait and open a new one when I come back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than having the downtime on the socket, have the downtime on whatever code processes the packets.

So the socket continues to receive like it normally would, but if it's on downtime, it just immediately drops the packet.

Not exactly the most efficient solution, but it's really easy to implement and might be useful as it leaves the node open in other cases for accepting different types of packets at different times.

Comment: I like it. The machine gets the data anyway and the actual socket-IO is fairly cheap in comparison (if done correctly :-). However, it seems like this could still result in race-conditions with the "stop time" and "other machine" unless there was additional information in the packets to determine who should handle them...

Comment: @pst assuming the packets have some kind of identifying information about them, then whatever signal turns it off should be able to tell it "do not accept packets after id 1400000" or something. This has the added advantage of having 1399999 processed even if it got delayed and reaches the nodes after the kill signal gets hit.

Comment: @pst Yes, there is that race condition. Fortunately, the switchover happens very rarely (it is part of a cluster and is triggered when the primary is down and we need to go to the hot backup). It is acceptable to lose a little bit of data during those times (exact correctness is not required, but we want to keep it as accurate as possible and definitely do not want to over count).